# Java, SQL Database Connection

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am C# developer and I don't know much about Java, normally in C# when I wanna connect to a database I use the following command:

```
static SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

I read a tutorial about making database connection (Sql Server 2008) in java in MSDN saying that the address must be declared this way:

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=JavaDB;user=UserName;password=*****";
```

I would like to if there's any way to declare the url the way I do in C#, I mean instead of

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
```

I directly point to the database

```
"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;"
```

thanks

Comment: In the Java world, there isn't another way.

Comment: I think the connection string is *driver specific*, so the JDBC syntax will differ from .NET drivers.

Comment: Directly pointing to the database_name.mdf is not possible through jdbc api...

Comment: As a Java developer that began working with .net technologies, I can advice you to don't focus on *I used to do it in this way and I want/prefer to keep it like that* instead try learning the new things. Take note that if you're going to Java (or any other PL) you should be open to new concepts/ideas or else you'll be ranting and won't learn anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the URL is prescribed by the JDBC specification, so all drivers will follow the structure `jdbc:<vendor-identifier>:<vendor-specific-url>`.

In Java creating the connection (at least via `java.sql.DriverManager`) is independent of the actual `Driver` implementation that creates the connection (in C# you create a typed vendor-specific connection).

The first part, `jdbc:<vendor-identifier>` is used as a selection mechanism so a `Driver` can quickly decide if it will accept an URL or not. Technically multiple driver implementations could accept an URL and create the connection. The `<vendor-identifier>` is usually the name of the database or company.

The `<vendor-specific-url>` will usually follow normal URL conventions (MS SQL Server JDBC URLS are an exception to that).

The format of the Microsoft JDBC driver is:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

See: [Building the Connection URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx).

Technically, Microsoft could have allowed only the database name in their `<vendor-specific-url>` and imply that it uses localhost but they decided not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation of the SQL JDBC driver does not mention any such thing

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378672(v=sql.110).aspx

so I assume it is not possible